# Too many days in month

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, calendar

I don't seem to be able to get my head around this one.

I'm generating a year calender in `MVC4`. But for some reason it shows too many days in the months.

It's probably an iteration mistake, but I don't seem to see it.

The .cshtml file

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>

    </td>
    @{
        for(int nr = 0; nr<12; nr++)
        {
            <td>
                <p>
                    @monthNames[nr]
                </p>
            </td>
        }
    }
</tr>
@{
    for(int day = 1; day <= 31; day++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>
                    @day
                </p>
            </td>
            @{
                for(int month = 1; month <= 12; month++)
                {
                    if (day <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month))
                    {
                        DateTime weekday = new DateTime(year, month, day);

                        <td>
                            @{
                                foreach (var thisEvent in events)
                                {
                                    if ((thisEvent.day == day) && (thisEvent.month == month) && (thisEvent.year == year))
                                    {
                                        <div style="background-color:@thisEvent.description.eventType.color;">
                                            @thisEvent.description.name
                                        </div>
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            <p>
                                @weekday.ToString("dddd", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("da-DK"))
                            </p>
                        </td> 
                    }
                }
            }
        </tr>
    }
}
</table>
```

**EDIT**

As a response to the question "Why is day loop before month?".
I did days before month because I'm making a table. And it seemed logical to make it top-down. and not left-right.

Comment: It seems natural that the first loop should be on months while the second one on days. IE twelve rows and 28..31 columns

Comment: It's just weird to me that you are iterating days 31 times first, what sort of layout are you going for.

I would iterate months, then inside of that days up to DaysInMonth

Comment: updated the question to elaborate

Comment: Based on your elaboration, then I'm failing to see the problem.  If you have months as columns then it makes sense that you would have to have 32 rows, one for the header and 31 others to cover all possible days for the longer months...  What, exactly, is it you want to "fix"?

Comment: "Too many days in the months" ... - What do you mean by this? Do you have an extra day in each month? Is it a table layout issue? What are you seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error.

I had to add an `else` to the

```
if (day <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month))
```

To make this

```
if (day <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month))
{
    <td>Day exist</td>
}
else
{
    <td>Day doesn't exist</td>
}
```

Comment: That was my suspicion (hence the "table layout issue" question in my comment on your question. Glad you got it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
        int year = 2014;
        for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++)
        {
            int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)
            for (int day = 1; day <= daysInMonth; day++)
            {
                DateTime weekday = new DateTime(year, month, day);

                <td>
                    @{
                        <span>@weekday</span>
                        <br />
                    }
                </td>
            }
        }
```

This will print each day in the year 2014, I believe.  Not sure where you were going with table rows and columns but I'll leave it at that.  Months, then days.

Comment: Get days in month before the inner for loop and inside outer for loop. Use that as terminating condition for inner loop. This way you will not have to check `day <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(year,month)` for each day.